# How can i add a base URL for all my BackboneJS Models/Collections REST calls?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Lets have the following code :

```
( function($) { 
    TeacherModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            uid : -1,
            name : ""
        }
    });

    TeachersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : TeacherModel,
        url : function() {
            return "/path/to/api" + "/teacher";
        }
    });
}());
```

I want to have `"/path/to/api"` as a global setting to Backbone (I know i can export it globally in `window`, but i want to set it somewhere in Backbone)

Is there a way and what is the best practice for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I usually tackle this is to create a base collection and inherit from it, like so:

```
BaseCollection = BackBone.Collection.extend({
    path: '/path/to/api'
});

TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    // path is now accessible from this and all other derived collections.
});
```

Comment: Inheritence is the last thing that comes to my mind when doing JavaScript :)
Seems like a nice solution

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it a viable option to put the path as a property on the AppView model?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie It depends on your needs, but yes that would also work. You can do inheritance with models and views just as you can do with collections.